# Access extended interface within the base interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface which includes an array of itself as children.

```ts
interface MyNestedInterface {
  value: string;
  children?: ReadonlyArray<MyNestedInterface>;
}
```

Now I want to make it so that the objects are only one level deep.

```ts
interface MyNestedInterface {
  value: string;
  children?: ReadonlyArray<Omit<MyNestedInterface, 'children'>>;
}
```

Finally, I want to extend `MyNestedInterface`.

```ts
interface ExtendedInterface extends MyNestedInterface {
  id: string;
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate it, with an `as const`, I get an error for the children because `id` does not exist on `MyNestedInterface`.

```ts
const obj: Readonly<ExtendedInterface> = {
  id: 'id1',
  value: 'value1',
  children: [
    // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not 
    // exist in type 'Pick<MyNestedInterface, "value">'.
    { id: 'id2', value: 'value2' },
    { id: 'id3', value: 'value3' },
  ],
} as const;
```

Is there a way to reference `this` inside of `MyNestedInterface` so that it knows about the extended properties, or else, some other way of getting around this without redeclaring `children` in `ExtendedInterface`?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8ByEDOkAmAkuNPEsgN4CwAUMsgG5wA2ArhAFzJ5SgDmAblr0EAC2DN8UCCAD8XAEoQ4+APYhm6AIJQocdAB4A8gFtgYAxmx4IRErEQQANMgDkYiVJmuAfD6E0AL60tKCQDuQAogAekCD4tsThZCgQsTL4OGhYuARJpI6UwsjA+Fw8-AHBNLQI6njIqgBGAFaKymoahjFxCXbJjj7IALxFdCVlbqUAjK5OxUxsnG6L7LPz4x6S0iBcANrF9AD0R8iRuqpQXEatEAhgyMzm0CzIJvqNXdwADnfAMOhkABrECqADuIGQ3ygql+UDAwFwLjg8Sm+FcyDUuGQoIeaWADVAyDA6F+bgACsAEEDLDkbP0CkgXAAiVYQZk+VwAOkOlAmXFcpQATHNGCx2AK2SLkIENvR6BR+WiAMyitmS8UQVUyuXIAC6G0CyDgWTqIDwAiAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty simple to do actually, using [polymorphic this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types):

```
interface MyNestedInterface {
  value: string;
  children?: ReadonlyArray<Omit<this, 'children'>>;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8ByEDOkAmAkuNPEsgN4CwAUMsgG5wA2ArhAFzJ5SgDmAblr0EAC2DN8UCCAD8XAEoQ4+APYhm6AIJQocdAB4A8gFtgYA2HE4ANMgDkYiVJn2AfG6E0AvrVqhIWEQUAFEAD0gQfAgiEiDyCAiZfBw0LFwCYkCyFGo6ZGB8Lh5+L18aWgR1PGRVACMAK0VlNQ1DcMjo2Ozgt2QAXkphAqKHQoBGexthpjZOB1n2Sen8p0lpEC4AbWH6ChGue0KAJinGFnZDxYhT5G87AHoH5ExVZGgoVSgcXcoDsfwAGYztcrhcIMC7it6Ht-kcgSDwWC5sC7DhRKpWJJXmBwsA8IdRNAIPYocgnsgAMJfaQIMCaZAwZhwPipOAgd66L7IInSYYAXRW3mQcFSVRAeAEQA)

Comment: Rofl.  I didn't know `this` was available as a type.